# Twitter Bootstrap's responsive CSS works on resized window, but not on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've used Twitter Bootstrap framework to build my newest site. I used `boostrap.responsive.css` to make it work on mobile devices. But it doesn't. It seems like it doesn't see the CSS at all. When I ran it on my Android phone, it was displaying my site just like my PC. But when I resize my browser window on PC, it works great. What can be the problem? I haven't messed with bootstrap's css.

When I ran `alert($(window).width());`, it returned 980.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure to include the meta viewport element as instructed in Bootstrap's [responsive docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive) so the layout will scale to the device width.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to call the bootstrap-responsive.css after the bootstrap.css in the order of your stylesheets.

ie 
bootstrap.css
bootstrap-responsive.css