# Website looses responsiveness on mobile due to iFrame?

Tags: php, html, css, iframe, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a website with Twitter Bootstrap and so far everything is running good when I run the site on my desktop and mobile. But my current problem is that when I use a masked domain, it removes responsiveness on mobile. And I saw a familiar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942287/twitter-bootstraps-responsive-css-works-on-resized-window-but-not-on-moble). But that suggests adding:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

But I already have that there, and the problem is still occurring. To see my problem you can see the functional site that works [here](http://harrisonbh.com/chatterr), and the non working one that is the iFrame to that page can be found [here](http://chatterr.me). I am using GoDaddy for my domain solution and the index file for `chatterr.me` iFrame I did't create nor have access to it. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: This takes me back to a SO post I read.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081315/why-developers-hate-iframes

Comment: @DarylGill Its not my fault, go daddy chooses to forward their domains that way. -_-

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using PHP in this case, as it would also allow you to style your iFrame and make it responsive.

```
<div class="iframe">
    <?php echo file_get_contents("http://example.com"); ?>
</div>
```

This will make the embed style-able, customizable, and, of course, responsive, as long as the original file was responsive as well.

Comment: Where did the function come from?

Comment: @HarrisonHoward the `get_file_contents` function is built into PHP

Comment: Its saying `Call to undefined function get_file_contents()`

Comment: @HarrisonHoward My bad - it's `file_get_contents()`

Comment: That seems to be glitchy and not work quite well. It doesn't seem to work with css well. Is there an alternative

Answer (score 0):

If you use a masked domain, the `<meta name="viewport">` necessary for the frame but you can't change this (you have this in your site and work fine), the perfect solution is no configure a redirect, put your domain in a "Hosted Domain" from the Hosting Control Panel.

With this the domain open or read a folder, ex: www.your-domain.com in the url is this, but show info from another-site.com/your-folder/.

More info at: https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/8342/adding-domain-names-to-your-hosting-account?locale=en (Click: Web/Classic (Hosting Control Panel))